# Consent screen appearing after Google Apps installation using oauth2 while it should not

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

We have recently migrated our app to oauth2 in the Google Apps Marketplace.

While the installation process goes very well, the first time the admin launch the app, a consent screen appears for the scopes that have already been accepted at the domaine level.

The call to oauth2 at the authentication is the following:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code
&client_id=....
&redirect_uri=...
&scope=email%20profile
&state=....
&access_type=online
&approval_prompt=auto
&include_granted_scopes=true
&hd=...
```

I do not see any reason for the consent screen to appear again.

Any idea?

Comment: Actually, the problem only occurs when the Admin click on the "Launch App" button after the installation. If the admin connect for the first time through the navigation bar and for all other users who will also connect through the navigation bar, the problem will not occur.

So, what is the difference between the navigation bar and that Launch App button?

Comment: It looks like it may be related to the amount of time that has passed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014892/do-we-need-to-wait-after-an-admin-accepts-an-app-marketplace-scopes-for-his-doma