# Do we need to wait after an admin accepts an app marketplace scopes for his domain in order to avoid consent screen?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We are integrating our app in the new Google Marketplace.
Our marketplace config in the developer console is ok.
Our oauth2/sso flow is ok (scopes match the ones setup in the console, auth params ok)
All users, when accessing our application through the Navigation bar, don't see any consent screen.  All is perfect … except the following :

when an admin user is installing our application for his domain for the first time, he is presented with the domain consent screen displaying the scopes defined in our marketplace config, which is fine, he accepts and is presented with a button "Launch app".  This link hit our server and a redirection is made to google auth in order to get the email and profile of that user.  The redirection happens quickly that the admin is presented with yet another consent screen displaying the exact same scopes … which is bad.
If we wait 10 - 20 seconds before clicking the 'Launch app' button and after having accepted the scopes for the domain, the redirection to google auth is done and no consent screen is presented to the admin.

Are we missing something?  Some sort of pooling technique with callback?  "Sleeping"?

Comment: Which authentication technology are you using to get the user's identity?

Answer (score 1):

The same happens with other apps available on Google Apps Marketplace.

I installed several apps from Marketplace (Mavenlink, Lucidchart, etc), and they showed exactly the same result. I was prompted with consent screen immediately after installing them. A bit later, and I was let in without prompting.

It seems that the information on the installed app is not immediately propagated through Google system. There is a short delay between the time the administrator installs an app to his domain, and the time that app becomes available on his domain.

Most users wouldn't mind to wait a minute after the installation. Unfortunately, a reviewer at Google is not that forgiving. If he is quick enough to start your app immediately after the installation, your app will be caught asking for consent, for which it will be rejected from Marketplace. Too bad.