# Consent screen appearing after domain installation (intermittently and timing based)

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I realize that this is a potentially duplicate question and is related to the following issues:

[Do we need to wait after an admin accepts an app marketplace scopes for his domain in order to avoid consent screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014892/do-we-need-to-wait-after-an-admin-accepts-an-app-marketplace-scopes-for-his-doma)

[Consent screen appearing after Google Apps installation using oauth2 while it should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998838/consent-screen-appearing-after-google-apps-installation-using-oauth2-while-it-sh?lq=1)

I currently don't have the commenting privilege yet, but was asked to post here by the Google Apps reviewer currently handling my case.

In any event, after going through the installation flow for my app numerous times at various speeds, I believe there is an issue related to timing and the propagation of permissions through the Google system.  If I do the installation and attempt to login really quickly I get presented with the consent pop up.  If I wait a few seconds then I do not get presented with the consent pop up.

I have verified that the OAuth scopes configured for the Google Apps Marketplace SDK in the developer console match those we are using during login.  I am using the [JavaScript client-side library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) that is mentioned in the [Apps Marketplace guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/building).

Any help would be appreciated as this issue is preventing my app from getting approved.

Comment: Haven't been able to make much progress here over the last few days.  I've tried altering scopes and tweaking when my JavaScript executes, but I'm still seeing the same timing dependent behavior.

Comment: I noticed that if you refresh the app listing in the domain admin (https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?hl=en&fral=1#AppsList:serviceType=MARKETPLACE) authorization is immediately detected.
I now check for the integration status of the domain before trying to detect authorization (gapi.auth.authorize with immediate: true).  This new check is made by calling https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/customerLicense.  I'm not sure if this is actually helping.  I'm noticing that it immediately returns that the integration is active, but auth is still not succeeding.

Comment: I did some testing and was able to replicate some delay in having the permissions propagate. Most of the time it was quick, but a few times I saw delays upwards of 30 or 40 seconds.

Comment: @SteveBazyl Thanks for taking the time to check out our app.  Any recommendations on what changes I can make to our implementation in order to get it approved?  Am I doing anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: Assuming we're talking about the same app, I didn't see anything out of the ordinary when I tried it. I asked the people reviewing apps to not block on this issue. There may be other issues still pending, but those can be followed up on separately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do we need to wait after an admin accepts an app marketplace scopes for his domain in order to avoid consent screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014892/do-we-need-to-wait-after-an-admin-accepts-an-app-marketplace-scopes-for-his-doma)